# Ruby on Rails: SSO implementation with LDAP using Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap, single-sign-on

I simply want to implement SSO in Rails 3 Application by having LDAP as a database for authentication using "Devise" gem.

I found one example http://corrupt.net/2010/07/05/LDAP-Authentication-With-Devise/ that just talk about implementation of LDAP in Rails application using "Devise" gem but not other features like SSO implementation, update LDAP information like password or any other.

Is there any demo/link/reference available for the same that could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently deploy an SSO platform with RubyCAS and LDAP, it work great but you need to generate a SSL cert to use it.

You can use multiple authentificators : I used LDAP with AD Microsoft and backup to MySQL Database if LDAP connector fail.

RubyCAS is now a standalone application, easier to customize.

For your apps using devise, you can use devise_cas_authenticatable gem, easy to setup. You only need to change the User model and add the rubycas server address into your devise.rb initiliazer.

Also you can refuse to create the user into the application if you want to refuse access for a new user who is not already created into the existant application.

https://github.com/rubycas/rubycas-server || 
https://github.com/nbudin/devise_cas_authenticatable

Hope it's clear.